# Adding JQuery mobile file in SharePoint 2013 Master Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, sharepoint

I am new to Sharepoint and I'm entry level programmer. I have a customized SharePoint 2013 master page. I want to use the JQuery swipe function in 3 pages in my SharePoint website. When I insert the jQuery mobile file in my master page some divs with ui-something class are incorporated into my master page, causing a mess.
Basically, in my SharePoint 2013 master page I have a SharePoint search box which I customized with my css file. When I add the mobile jQuery the search box get all messed up. 
Is there some secrete in how to use the mobile jQuery in SharePoint 2013 Master Page?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile doesn't work so well with SharePoint 2013.

I suggest if you are after a responsive mobile experience, look at PnP's Responsive UI

http://dev.office.com/blogs/web-cast-responsive-ui-package-for-sharepoint

You can add the responsive ui to your SP2013 via User Custom Actions and I have a simple tool to do this, if you don't have powershell access to your farm.

http://johnliu.net/blog/2016/3/sp-responsive-ui-three-files-ucacp